# Cloud Messaging error: Data Must be a non=null object

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a cloud function that send a notification when doc is created on firestore. all is good except the data paramater of the notification.

it generates the error:
data must be non-nullable object.

code is:

```
exports.ReviewNotification = functions.firestore
.document("ReviewsCollection/{reviewId}")
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const mydocument = snap.data();
  const businessprofileid = mydocument.Review_bpid;
  const reviewid = context.params.reviewId;
  console.log(reviewid);
  database.collection("BusinessProfilesCollection")
      .doc(businessprofileid)
      .get().then((secsnapshot) => {
        const seconddocument = secsnapshot.data();
        const userid = seconddocument.Profile_user_id;
        const businessprofilename = seconddocument.Profile_name;
        console.log(userid);
        database.collection("UsersCollection")
            .doc(userid)
            .get().then((lastsnapshot) => {
              const lastdocment = lastsnapshot.data();
              const mytoken = lastdocment.User_device_token;
              const data = "Type: Review, ID: "+
                 reviewid + ", Extra: temp";
              const message ={
                "notification": {
                  title: businessprofilename,
                  body: "You have new review",
                },
                "data": data,
                "token": mytoken,
              };
              const response = admin.messaging().send(message);
              console.log("Completed");
              console.log(response);
            });
      });
  return null;
});
```

there is a similar question I've checked its answers, suggesting solution is to be :

```
"data": {data},
```

this works, but the the message.data received on the app is ass following:

```
{data: Type: Review, ID: vs3qxYWu5i1kQS5q8NZw, Extra: temp}
```

I need it to without the word data:, lile that:

```
{Type: Review, ID: vs3qxYWu5i1kQS5q8NZw, Extra: temp}
```

so in the notification onclick function I can match on the keys and get the values.

Comment: problem was that you can't put variable inside the "data" paramater. because it can be someting other string. Solution is to put instide string method as below 

      "data": {Type: "Review", ID: String(reviewid), Extra: String(businessprofileid)},

Answer (score 1):

problem was that you can't put variable inside the "data" paramater. because it can be someting other string. Solution is to put instide string method as below

```
"data": {Type: "Review", ID: String(reviewid), Extra: String(businessprofileid)},
```